# Maximum cardinality of S

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

1.Let $S$ be a subset of ${1,2,...,n}$ such that for every $a,b$ in $S$ $a+b$ not is square
What is the  maximum cardinality of $S$

The numbers of form $4k+1$

Comment: This looks like it's been cut and pasted from a problem list, in which case it does not belong here.  MO is for research-level mathematics.

Comment: the problem is computational, similar  the sidon set

Comment: Looks like the post is not finished. For what it worth, the numbers of form $3k+1$ are better example than $4k+1$.

Comment: $11n/32$ ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Assuming $a \not= b$, the first 100 values are 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 5 6 7 7 7 7 8 8 8 9 9 10 11 11 11 12 12 13 13 14 14 14 14 15 15 16 16 17 17 18 18 19 19 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 21 21 22 22 23 23 24 24 25 25 26 26 27 27 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 29 29 30 30 31 31 32 32 33 33 34 34 35 35 36 36 37 37 37 37 37 37 37 37 37 37 37 38 38

Comment: @mathworker21 Yep, that is quite a famous theorem. Also, if we allow to take two different sets $A,B$ of equal cardinality such that for no $a\in A, b\in B$, $a+b$ is a square, the answer becomes $3n/8$ (I learned it from Zachary Chase).